# Publish Action to Facebook Got Exception

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

I got exception when I try to publish action to facebook.

```
Exception :
{"error":{"message":"(#3502) Object at URL localhost/XXX has og:type of 'website'. The property 'myobject' requires an object of og:type 'mynamespace:myobject'. ","type":"OAuthException","code":3502}} 


FB.api(
            '/me/mynamespace:myaction',
            'post',
            { myobject: url,
                access_token: accessToken
            },
            function (response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    Alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                }
            });
```

My Url Generated from a model from backend:
My Url : `http://localhost/post/og/`

```
public ActionResult og(int id)
        {
            return View(new OGModel(id));
        }
```

View :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# @Model.NameSpace: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/@Model.NameSpace#">
        <title>@Model.Title</title>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="@Model.AppId" /> 
        <meta property="og:type" content="@Model.NameSpace:myobject" /> 
        <meta property="og:url" content="@Model.SharingLink">
        <meta property="og:title" content="@Model.Title" /> 
        <meta property="og:image" content="@Model.Image" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked at the source of your generated page to see if your view is outputting what you expect?

Comment: yes cpilko, it just what i expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't post OG actions where the object URLs are on localhost because Facebook's crawler won't be able to reach them and read the meta tags.
The URL of all your objects needs to be accessible from the internet; specifically by Facebook's crawler.

You can check what, if anything, Facebook detects on your URL by using [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)